# jquery nth-child(n) not working right

Tags: jquery, html

I want to alter the margin-right on the 4th image in a list.

The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="moduletable_lbx">
<div class="custom_lbx"  >
<p>
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-001.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-001-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

I created a little jQuery:

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx img:nth-child(4) ").css( "margin-right","0px");
```

but it doesn't work. I noticed that if I put 1 instead of 4 then all the right margins are taken off. If I put 2 then no margins are taken off.

Comment: your jQuery line means (in human words) "get the 4th image which is a child of `.moduletable_lbx` and set the css for it", clearly it is not what you need since `.moduletable_lbx` doesn't have an `img` as a child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change it to this:

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx a:nth-child(4) img ").css( "margin-right","0px");
```

```js
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx a:nth-child(4) img ").css("margin-right", "0px");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduletable_lbx">
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the code. Does `moduletable_lbx` have any children that are anchors?

Comment: You have `.moduletable_lbx > a:nth-child(4)` which selects only anchors that are children of elements with the class `moduletable_lbx`. I see none of those in the example code the OP posted.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the *4n* element of the container, and then, the img.

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx a:nth-child(4n) img").css( "margin-right","0px");
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx:nth-child(4) img:nth-child(1)").css( "margin-right","0px");
```

So you should select the parent index at the end the img is always the first one.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach , utilizing [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) , which applies a 0-based index ; retrieving the 4th element with index `3` : 0,1,2,**3** . `nth-` selectors apply 1-based index : 1,2,3,**4**

[:nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived
>   from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning
>   that the counting starts at 1. For other selector expressions such as
>   :eq() or :even jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting. Given
>   a single  containing two `<li>`'s, $( "li:nth-child(1)" ) selects the
>   first `<li>` while  `$( "li:eq(1)" )` selects the second.

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx img:eq(3)").css( "margin-right","0px")
```

```js
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx img:eq(3)").css("margin-right", "0px")
```

```css
img {
  margin-right:24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduletable_lbx">
<div class="custom_lbx">
<p>
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-001.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-001-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-002-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-003-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-004-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<a title="" href="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005.jpg" data-lightbox="group:columbia-Road;titlePosition:over;transitionIn:elastic; "><img src="/images/lyndonosborn/columbia-lbx/columbia-Road-005-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
    </p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - I went with

```
jQuery(".moduletable_lbx a:nth-child(4) img ").css( "margin-right","0px");
```

and it works fine.